# Apache Kafka (v3) - KTable behaving like a KStream?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new to Apache Kafka and my understanding is that when using KTable, you only get the last update to a record. However, I am getting back all the matching records.

Please consider the sample code below.

Add 3 records

```java
producer.send(
    new ProducerRecord<>(
        topicName, 
        "http://www.simpsons.com", 
        "one"));
    
producer.send(
    new ProducerRecord<>(
        topicName, 
        "http://www.simpsons.com", 
        "two"));
        
producer.send(
    new ProducerRecord<>(
        topicName, 
        "http://www.familyguy.com", 
        "three"));
```

Try to find the last recorded information for the record with key `http://www.simpsons.com`

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, String.format("%s", uuid));
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, connectionString);
       
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
// ** create the KTable instance **
KTable<String, String> myTable = builder.table(topicName, Consumed.with(AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST));

myTable.toStream()
    .filter((k,v) -> k.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.simpsons.com"))
    .print(Printed.<String, String>toSysOut()
    .withLabel("KTable"));

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), new StreamsConfig(props));

kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
kafkaStreams.start();

Thread.sleep(5000);

kafkaStreams.close();
```

This is the output

```
[KTable]: http://www.simpsons.com, one
[KTable]: http://www.simpsons.com, two
```

I must be missing something basic here. My expectation is that this should print out just one record.
`http://www.simpsons.com, two`

Any guidance will be much appreciated. :-)

Comment: Are you starting the streams app after the publish is finished? If not, try giving that a go. It could be the first line of output is printed before the 'two' has published.

Comment: Also try chaning AutoOffsetReset to latest.

Comment: @JoeM I'm running this in their individual unit tests. The first test runs and add data. A few seconds later, the second test prints it out. 
I tried with AutoOffsetReset.LATEST and it printed nothing.